# Javascript - How to ensure callback function has terminated before executing main function again

Tags: javascript, ajax, callback, synchronization

Hi everyone my question is this:

I want to call a function ("funcA") which returns some data (ajax call) that are then used via a callback function. When the callback function execution is completed I want to call the same function ("funcA") with different parameters.

What I want is the best way to ensure that the callback function has been completed when the funcA is called for the second time.

```
         funcA("firstParameter", function(callbackData){/*useCallbackData...*/ });
```

//when funcA callback function completes execution proceed to run funcA with ("secondParameter") as parameter.

```
         funcA("secondParameter", function(callbackData){/*useCallbackData... */});
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Just nest them ?

```
funcA("firstParameter", function(callbackData1){

    funcA("secondParameter", function(callbackData2){


    });

});
```

Another option would be promises, but for just two async functions, nesting really is the easiest !

Comment: Is it posible to be done with promises? How am I supposed to return the deferred.promise() if I have to return other data too?

Comment: Of course it can be done with promises, but do you want to use native promises, which are only supported in newer browsers, do you want to use a library that implements promises, like Bluebird, or are you already using jQuery, which has it's own version of promises etc.

Comment: Moreover, if the first callback function (I am referring to the callback, not the first funcA ) manipulates the DOM manipulates the DOM and the second callback function depends on the manipulated DOM, and the first callback function takes more time to execute than the second funcA takes to get the callbackData2 with the ajax call then this will fail. Am I wrong?

Comment: You're wrong, any DOM manipulation done before the second `funcA` is called, is available in the callback for the second one. DOM manipulation is synchronous, so that's not an issue.

Comment: funcA("firstParameter", function(callbackData1){

    for(var i=0; i<=10000000000000000000; i++){
         if (i=10000000000000000000){
              //manipulate the DOM
         }
    }



    funcA("secondParameter", function(callbackData2){

       //use manipulated DOM
    });

});

In that case isn't it posible to fail?

Comment: sorry I don't know how to insert code style in comments

Comment: You can also keep track of what state the code is currently in with a `state` variable.